# Quartz Composer in iPhone UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, quartz-graphics, cgcontext, quartz-composer

I am trying to embed a Quartz Composer document in an iPhone app. I know Quartz Composer support was added in iPhone OS 3.1 (at least, that's what Wikipedia says) but I can't find any good resources on how to do this. Do I use CGContext? Or are there more friendly ways to add a Quartz Composer composition?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't trust everything you read on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quartz Compositions do not run on iPhone.

The Quartz Composer Editor application *is* included with the iPhone SDK download (and with the basic Xcode Developer Tools package) — which is where you may have seen it mentioned in proximity to iPhone — but compositions only run on the desktop OS.